# Android - Webview Progressbar

Tags: java, android

I have added the progressbar above the webview.
Whenever the i click a link, I just made the progressbar to visible.

I want to have the progressbar overlay on the webview and i want to show the percentage of progress bar. I know css, but i don't know how to change the position of progressbar in android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView web;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
 // request the progress-bar feature for the activity
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

    // set a webChromeClient to track progress    
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            // update the progressBar
            MainActivity.this.setProgress(progress * 100);
        }
    });


    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("url");

}

// To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

To display progressbar percentage, do i need to modify this code? or can i extend the functionality from this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To show a "page load" progress bar, use this:

in onCreate():

```
// request the progress-bar feature for the activity
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

// set a webChromeClient to track progress    
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
{
 public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
 {
   // update the progressBar
   MyActivity.this.setProgress(progress * 100);
 }
});
```

This will show using built-in styling at the top of the screen, just like the built-in browser.

If instead you want to display and update your own ProgressBar, the process is similar, get a handle to your progress bar:

```
ProgressBar myProgress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
```

.
.
.
and in the onProgressChanged() function, use this:

```
myProgress.setProgress(progress * 100);
```

instead of MyActivity.this.setProgress().

Further, can't use a LinearLayout if you want to have ProgressBar appear in front of the WebView.  Use a RelativeLayout with centerInParent="true", and list the ProgressBar after the WebView in your layout.

Comment: I added your lines below  `web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient()); Unfortunately app has stopped. There is a fata error in main.`

Comment: I made the following changes in your code obviously. MyActivity => MainActivity, myWebView to web and WebvView to WebView

Comment: it's WebChromeClient, not WebViewClient

Comment: using the "built-in" progressBar technique, you really don't need your WebViewClient at all, just the WebChromeClient

Comment: This is what i have now. I updated the question. Still app stopped without running!

Comment: getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);  This line must be added before setContentView. But links are opening in browser!

Comment: I still need to use WebClientView to load the page in the app itself.